# Sound recording click in beginning

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audio-recording, audio-processing

I'm getting a click sound just when starting the recording in the app. I have no clue where it comes from, thinking it might come from the tap on the button but that seems far fetched.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
private var recorderSettings: [String: Any] {
    [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
}

audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileUrl, settings: recorderSettings)
try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [])

audioRecorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
audioRecorder?.record()
meteringTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

self.audioRecorder?.updateMeters()
self.soundSamples[self.currentSample] = self.audioRecorder?.averagePower(forChannel: 0) ?? 0
self.currentSample = (self.currentSample + 1) % self.numberOfSamples
})
```

Comment: Is this on a physical device or simulator?

Comment: @Adrian on device

Comment: I haven't recorded on device before, but I'd have a look through Apple's documentation online. I recently did playback on a device and I ended up getting the audio ready in `AppDelegate`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66937105/4475605

Answer (score 3):

A "click" is usually an indication of either an impulse audio value (e.g., a single 1 in a stream of 0's) or a significant non-linearity (e.g., either jumping into or out of a full-volume signal from 0). It's probably not the actual sound of a key or mouse click! (Experiment: put a fixed delay between the click time and the recording onset, and see if the click remains audible.)

If the situation is one where Apple doesn't have built in functions to deal with this common problem, perhaps you can start your recording by gradually fading up the volume at the onset. A fade up over the course of 1/50th of a second might be sufficient for avoiding audible signal discontinuities. I often use fades of 1/40th of a second or less on 44100 fps data as an alternative to going from volume A to volume B instantaneously in my Java audio coding. (In your case, volume A is 0 and volume B is your recording volume.)